# IE 10 with no add on mode, ruins my all css settings of web app

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

[image]I have Web App, which works fine in normal mode and on any version of IE, FF and chrome as well, but when I run it **On IE 10 with No add on mode, it ruins my settings of css**!

What can be done?
Even reinstalling IE also doesn't helps!

Please Guide me!

Comment: Is that youe IE beta Version.? I got the Issue in my App, Once I install the Valid IE 10 , It works fine

Comment: No, not beta version! Have updated IE details!

Comment: Did you use any Response.Write() in Page_Load function.

Comment: No! It was working fine till I haven't run it like start->IE->No add on mode or from Tools->Manage-Add-ons->disable.

Comment: IE is such a burden. I hope you get an answer to your question, I'm sure to face the issue someday soon XD

Answer (score 0):

It may help you

1. Remove the older doctype declaration of: **`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`**
2. Replace it with the newer HTML5 declaration: **`<!DOCTYPE html>`**

   **`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`**

Comment: Tried this too! didn't help!

Comment: can u send the Issue UI screen and Working UI screnn to this sendspace.com, share the Link

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was IE version...

In my case, updated version was RTM.. Which caused problem! when updated it,it worked fine.